# Xcode command line tools doesn't see .dylib files

Tags: xcode, opencv, xcode4.2, dylib

In terminal i've installed cmake and build OpenCV. When i'm typing `ls /usr/local/lib` i've got a lot of files .dylib
I have to link the .dylib files provided by OpenCV into project
I need to link framework in my project. I open Command line tools (by Add Files to "...") and text in `/usr/local/lib`. And there are no .dylib
Tell me somebody what's wrong
Thanks !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your Xcode project is configured to build against an SDK. The the OpenCV libraries are not part of the SDK, they're installed on your system. Switch your Xcode project to using a "Base SDK" of "Current OS X" and the problem should go away.

Comment: In my Build Settings I found just "Base SDK" and i can choose a version. How to specify of using "Base SDK"?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Can you clarify?

Comment: how to determine Base SDK for Current OSX?

Comment: You should have an option in the pop-up menu when you change the Base SDK build setting that says "Current OS X". That's what you want.